# Doctrine getVirtualColumn

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I'm new in Symfony2 and upgrading an application from Propel to Doctrine, because Propel is not really supported anymore. In Propel it was possible to get a custom column (for example COUNT(DISCOUNT ....)) from de database with withColumn() and getVirtualColumn().

This is the Doctrine code to get the information of a product:

```
$queryBuilder
    ->select('product', 'votable', $queryBuilder->expr()->countDistinct ('vote.ipAddress').' AS voteCount')
    ->from('Generic\ProductBundle\Entity\Product', 'product')
    ->leftJoin ('\Generic\VotableBundle\Entity\Votable', 'votable', Join::WITH, 'votable.id = product.votable')
    ->leftJoin ('\Generic\VotableBundle\Entity\Vote', 'vote', Join::WITH, 'votable.id = vote.votable')
    ->groupBy('product.id');

$products = $queryBuilder->getQuery()->getResult();

foreach ($products as $product)
{
    print $product->getTitle();
    print $product->getVotable()->getCreatedAt();

    // But how to get the voteCount column?. In Propel it was possible to say $product->getVirtualColumn('voteCount')
}
```

I already tried ScalarResults and Hydrator. If I dump($product) then you see for every product 2 arrays with in the first array the "Product" entity and in the second array the "Voteable" entity with "voteCount". I can loop through the results and combine everything, but that not the way to work. Also I takes a lot of memory with big results.

And how is it possible to get de voteCount column in the Twig template?

Hope someone can help? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

As explained in the documentation. http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html#pure-and-mixed-results

It would be

```
foreach ($rows as $row)
{
    print $row[0]->getTitle();
    print $row['voteCount'];
}
```